# Products not correctly sorted according to name

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, sorting

I have 3 products in a category. I need to sort it according to the order listed below

```
    **-------Expected order-------**
    Armani Code For Men 50ml EDT
    Armani Code For Men 100ml EDT
    Armani Code For Men 200ml EDT
```

But when i sort the products according to the name i get the order listed below

```
**-------Sorted according to name-------**
        Armani Code For Men 100ml EDT
        Armani Code For Men 200ml EDT
        Armani Code For Men 50ml EDT
```

How can i correct it to display the products according to the expected order?

**-----------------Update-----------------------------**

The issue seems to be that the collection is not being sort by natural sort. How can i natural sort a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting by name sorts alphabetically and so what you're seeing is correct. AFAIK MySQL has no natural sort and neither does Magento.

A workaround may be to manually force the order of the products using the "Position" field see screenshot below:

[image: Setting product display position within a category]